# How to align linearlayout to vertical center?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to align LinearLayout's vertical center which shows following pic (skycolor border) to delete button's vertical center.

so I set the gravity of id:groupNumbers to center_vertical.

but no changed.

How to align id:groupNumbers to button's center?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/groupNumbers"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSelected01"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSelected02"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_deleteNum"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check gravity attribute for linear layout.

Comment: Apply `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to your layout...

Comment: use relative layout, it makes these alignments too easy.
we can acheive this with LinearLayout also, but with bit pain.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Change orientation and gravity in

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/groupNumbers"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

to

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

You are adding orientation: horizontal, so the layout will contain all elements in single horizontal line. Which won't allow you to get the element in center.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I fixed to do this. I set first layout's gravity to center.
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Comment: but this isn't what he want... he wants a single horizontal line in the center of vertical screen...

Answer (score 38):

use `android:layout_gravity` instead of `android:gravity`

`android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.
`android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful, even though the answer is so old.

Answer (score 11):

Use `layout_gravity` instead of `gravity`. `layout_gravity` tells the parent where it should be positioned, and `gravity` tells its child where they should be positioned.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/groupNumbers"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 8):

For me, I have fixed the problem using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in a parent `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout ... >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

For a box that appears in the center - horizontal & vertical - I got this to work with just one LinearLayout.  The [answer from Viswanath L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20185370/2162226) was very helpful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Error"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Error-Message"
        android:textColor="#000" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Ok" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use RelativeLayout inside LinearLayout

example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Status"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:weightSum` property to the parent LinearLayout and give value 3. Then in the children LinearLayout use `android:layout_weight` 2 and 1 respectively. Then in the First Chil LinearLayout use `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`. As shown in the following code

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/status_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="00"
                            android:textColor="@color/red"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
                            />
                          <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/status_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="00"
                            android:textColor="@color/red"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <Button
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="Delete"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change set orientation of linearlayout programmatically by:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout =new linearLayout(this);//just to give the clarity
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```