# Android centering linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I read this: [How to align linearlayout to vertical center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185340/how-to-align-linearlayout-to-vertical-center)
But it didn't help me

Basically I am trying to center 2 `ImageButtons` in the middle of my screen. The two buttons are horizontally orientated in a `linearLayout`.

I tried to use a `relativeLayout` with vertical orientation to center the two `imagebuttons` in the center in the vertical direction but that doesnt seem to do the job.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.max.testcase.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="loadSomething"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Click here to load the site"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/icon1"
                android:onClick="method1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
                android:maxWidth="350dp"
                android:maxHeight="350dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/icon1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/icon2"
                android:onClick="method2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight= "1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="350dp"
                android:maxHeight="350dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/icon2"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The two buttons keep sticking to the top button bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to the **RelativeLayout**, 
and replace `android:layout_gravity="center"` with

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

in its child **LinearLayout**

Make it like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.max.testcase.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="loadSomething"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Click here to load the site"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/icon1"
                android:onClick="method1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
                android:maxWidth="350dp"
                android:maxHeight="350dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/icon1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/icon2"
                android:onClick="method2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight= "1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="350dp"
                android:maxHeight="350dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/icon2"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What if I want to add a footer down? Now that it's match_parent I can't add anything underneath.
I tried to change it to wrap_content and then add a footer with relative_layout, but this messes with the buttons again

Comment: @Jbv2 In that case, just add that footerview inside this RelativeLayout (one with the height match_parent), and align it to the bottom as - `android:alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 1):

your question seems bit unclear but hope this tip will help you

**android:layout_gravity**

- `android:layout_gravity` is used to set the position of an element in its parent (e.g. a child `View` inside a `Layout`).
  Supported by LinearLayout and FrameLayout

**android:gravity**

`android:gravity` is used to set the position of content inside an element (e.g. a text inside a `TextView`).

to get and idea copy this XML and understand how it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/third"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/third"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/third"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all parent layouts of `Button`'s have set `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Then apply `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` works with the children of RelativeLayout, not for the RelativeLayout itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="loadSomething"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Click here to load the site"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#ff00"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/icon1"
                android:onClick="method1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
                android:maxWidth="350dp"
                android:maxHeight="350dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/icon2"
                android:onClick="method2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight= "1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="350dp"
                android:maxHeight="350dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.max.testcase.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="loadSomething"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Click here to load the site"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/icon1"
            android:onClick="method1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
            android:maxWidth="350dp"
            android:maxHeight="350dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/icon1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/icon2"
            android:onClick="method2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight= "1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="350dp"
            android:maxHeight="350dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/icon2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add layout_gravity and gravity attribute in root linear layout with value center vertical it will make all his child align in center vertical.
Note: make child height wrap_content, to achieve this. if your child height is match_parent than this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
A simple layout design for center two image button

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="loadSomething"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Click here to load the site"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/icon1"
            android:onClick="method1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
            android:maxWidth="350dp"
            android:maxHeight="350dp"
            android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"
            android:src="@mipmap/minus_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/icon2"
            android:onClick="method2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight= "1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="350dp"
            android:maxHeight="350dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"
            android:src="@mipmap/plus_icon"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```