# How to align item vertically in a layout?

Tags: android, android-listview

I try to dynamically populate a list and I have been following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185340/how-to-align-linearlayout-to-vertical-center) but for a reason my items aren't one under each other but one next to each others.
[image: my actual display]

This is how I populate it using java:

```java
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_apero, container, false);

        TextView name = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.name_apero);
        name.setText(detailApero.getName());
        TextView date = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.date_apero);
        date.setText(detailApero.getDate());

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.vertical_layout_ingredient);
        LinearLayout a = new LinearLayout(root.getContext());
        a.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Button b = new Button(root.getContext());
            b.setText("Button "+i);
            a.addView(b);
        }
        ll.addView(a);
```

and finally the xml structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".ui.home.AperoDetailFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_apero"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_apero"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.907"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ingredient_apero"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="426dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.111"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.399">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vertical_layout_ingredient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredient_title_apero"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:text="Liste d'achat:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.005"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.125" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't understand why they aren't coming one under each other, how can I do that ?

Comment: LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL to LinearLayout.VERTICAL

Comment: What happend when you change `LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL` to `Linearlayout.VERTICAL`  ? will it work?

Comment: it was right under my eyes for 20 minutes... thank you very much feel free to post an answer